# How to generate hebrew strings in python 3?

Tags: python, string, unicode, pydev, hebrew

I'm trying to create hebrew strings but get syntax errors. It works in the IDLE shell but not in Pydev.
Here's what I've tried so far:

```
s = 'מחרוזת בעברית' #works in the shell only
s = u'מחרוזת בעברית' #doesn't work at all
s = unicode("מחרוזת בעברית", "UTF-8") #also doesn't work at all
```

I get a syntax error: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xee'.
What does it mean and what shall I do to create hebrew strings?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work at all, or it works in the shell only, are you getting the same errors in each case?

Comment: Apologies - I answered for Python 2.6, so I deleted it. I hear some questions of unicode representation are not yet resolved in Python 3 -- does the same work in your toolchain in python 2.6? It should.

Comment: @NinjaCat same error in each case: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xee'

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical when you say that you use `u"..."`... that literal is gone in Python 3, see here: http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit On 3.1 this gives me a syntax error, so are you sure you are not using Python 2.6, it makes a world of difference when it comes to unicode and literals.

Comment: Typing any non-ASCII characters into the ‘shell’ or ‘console’ is extremely troublesome on Windows, and so best avoided. You are usually inserting the characters encoded in your machine's system code page, which is locale-dependent but never UTF-8. If you have a Hebrew locale you are using code page 1255. You can get this encoding (also misleadingly known as the ‘ANSI’ code page) using the `'mbcs'` encoding, on Windows only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does your source file start with a `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` line? Is your file actually encoded as utf-8 (and not some other encoding)?

It's supposed to work (the first line, other lines are not valid Python 3).

Comment: Thanks. adding this comment to the source file worked. But I still have questions:
1. I thought the interpreter ignores all comments. Are there any other comment formats which aren't ignored?
2. The thing worked for me even after I deleted this comment. I mean, once I put the comment, it worked even after removing the comment. Can you explain that?

Comment: I had thought of it after I answered, but IIRC, Python3's default source code encoding became UTF-8 with Python 3 (under Python 2, it was ascii), so this comment is now useless. Yes, all comment *but* this one are ignored, it's a special case (the only one I think).

So for Python 3, the only possible problem was then the encoding of your file itself.